# Firefox opens clean window from application

Tags: 18.04, firefox, mime-type

When I open a link from another application, like Slack or an IDE,
Firefox opens a new window without any of my extensions installed or enabled. It also does this when there is a Firefox window already open.
(I would expect a new tab to be opened in the already existing window)
Also, all my sessions are gone in this new window.
The new window is not a private window but a "normal" Firefox window.

This might be a Firefox issue but as this only happens on Ubuntu and not on any other os (that is: Windows and OSX) it might be Ubuntu.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04

Hope someone knows what is going on here. And let Firefox open a standard window with my plugins and sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Oke, so apparently I had multiple Firefox profiles.
And a clean profile was used when opening from the application.

In a terminal I did:

```
firefox -P
```

Removed the redundant profile and now it works as expected.